# Can you make a clickevent with the masterdetailpage icon/text?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i have a rootpage with a menupage (that works as my masterdetailpage) and my contentpage. when I click my menupage icon/text i want the menupage (mdp) to initialize its component when I click the icon/text.

Is it possible?

This is the code that I currently have.

```
public RootPage ()
    {
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar (this, false);
        var theMenu = new MenuPage (this);

        theMenu.Title = "Click";
        theMenu.Icon = "Icon-Small-40.png";

        //can I make a click with the theMenu.Title or Icon above?

        Master = theMenu;

        NavigationPage page = new NavigationPage(new StartPage ());
        Detail = page;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if below code helps you

```
namespace LoginNavigation
{
public class RootPage:MasterDetailPage
{
MenuPage menuPage;
public RootPage ()
{

menuPage = new MenuPage ();

menuPage.Menu.ItemSelected += (sender, e) => NavigateTo (e.SelectedItem as MenuItemForMaster);

Master = menuPage;
Detail = new NavigationPage (new TimeSheet()){
};
}

void NavigateTo (MenuItemForMaster menu)
{
if (menu == null)
return;

Page displayPage = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance (menu.TargetType);
//Detail = displayPage;
Detail = new NavigationPage (displayPage) { BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("008dce"),BackgroundColor  = Color.FromHex("008dce")};

menuPage.Menu.SelectedItem = null;
IsPresented = false;
}
}
}
```

*in MenuPage , i have*

```
Menu = new MenuListView ();
Menu.RowHeight = 44;
Menu.SeparatorColor = Color.FromHex ("e8e8e8");
Menu.SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.Default;
```

*menuListView and DataClass is as follows*

```
namespace LoginNavigation
{
public class MenuListView : ListView
{
public MenuListView ()
{
List<MenuItemForMaster> data = new MenuListData ();

ItemsSource = data;
VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
BackgroundColor = Color.Accent;

var cell = new DataTemplate (typeof(MenuCell));
//cell.SetBinding (MenuCell.TextProperty, "Title");
//cell.SetBinding (MenuCell.ImageSourceProperty, "IconSource");
this.HasUnevenRows = false;
ItemTemplate = cell;
}

namespace LoginNavigation
{
public class MenuListData : List<MenuItemForMaster>
{
public MenuListData ()
{
this.Add (new MenuItemForMaster () { 
Name = “"
ImageSource = "paper_plane.png", 
TargetType = typeof(TimeSheet)
});
this.Add (new MenuItemForMaster () { 
Name = "Extn : 3969", 
ImageSource = "phone_reciever.png", 
TargetType = typeof(TimeSheet)
});
this.Add (new MenuItemForMaster () { 
Name = "TimeSheet", 
ImageSource = "Calender.png", 
TargetType = typeof(TimeSheet)
});

this.Add (new MenuItemForMaster () { 
Name = "Omega", 
ImageSource = "Notes.png", 
TargetType = typeof(Omega)
});

}
}
}
```

*finally this is MenuItemForMaster*

```
 namespace LoginNavigation
    {

    public class MenuItemForMaster
    {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ImageSource { get; set; }

    public Type TargetType { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: i am away right now from my computer, will test tomorrow if it works!