# Customize ListView without native renderer

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to customize a Xamarin.Forms ListView(or a Cell) without a custom renderer ?

Every result I found explains with a native renderer, but it's not what I want.

I just want to customize my ListView or cells of my ListView from my shared project PCL, to keep the force of Xamarin.Forms, and share every UI code between applications.

EDIT 1:

```
public class TappticCell : ViewCell
{
    #region BindableProperty Fields

    public static readonly BindableProperty NameProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("Name", typeof(string), typeof(string), "");

    public static readonly BindableProperty NameColorProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("NameColor", typeof(Color), typeof(Color), Color.Transparent);

    #endregion

    #region BindableProperty Properties

    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(NameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
    }

    public Color NameColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(NameColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NameColorProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Fields

    private readonly Label _nameLabel;
    private readonly StackLayout _stackLayout;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public TappticCell()
    {
        [...]
        _nameLabel = new Label { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand };

        _nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Name");
        _nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextColorProperty, "NameColor");

        [...]
    }

    #endregion
}
```

My problem is the second SetBinding with the BindableProperty NameColor doesn't work ... Here my use in XAML

```
<cells:TappticCell Image="{Binding Image}"
                           Name="{Binding Name}"
                           BackgroundColor="Gray"
                           NameColor="{Binding Favorite, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToColor}}"
                           TextSize="30" />
```

When I use this with an ImageCell, it works great, but not with my custom cell ...

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to do it in XAML or code? Have a look at the `ListView.ItemTemplate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if i understood you clearly , you want to customise appearance of cell.
In that case i would recommend using viewCell for displaying the UI content .
Here is how u  write viewCell class

```
public class EffortMenuCell:ViewCell
    {
        static int i = 0;
        public EffortMenuCell() : base() {

            var newLabel2 = new Label () {VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand };


            newLabel2.SetBinding (Label.TextProperty, "nameLabel");
            var time = new Label ();
            time.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand;
            time.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
            time.SetBinding (Label.TextProperty, "timespan");
            var tempLayout2 = new StackLayout ();

            //tempLayout2.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
            tempLayout2.Padding = new Thickness(20,0,20,0);
            tempLayout2.Spacing = 20;

            tempLayout2.Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;

// based on index Different Row appearance ,

            if (i == 0) {
                tempLayout2.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex ("e0e0e0");
                newLabel2.TextColor = Color.FromHex ("a4a4a4");
                time.TextColor = Color.FromHex ("01bcbc");
                this.IsEnabled = false;
                i++;
            } else {
                if (i <= 4) {
                    tempLayout2.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
                    newLabel2.TextColor = Color.Black;
                    time.TextColor = Color.FromHex ("007fbf");
                    i++;
                }
                if (i == 5) {
                    i = 0;
                }
            }

            tempLayout2.Children.Add (newLabel2);
            tempLayout2.Children.Add (time);
            this.View = tempLayout2;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes it's exactly what I wanted to do ! Thanks ! I thought I had to do a custom renderer to get a uniform UI between platforms !

Comment: Yes :) but I have another question ! I had a problem with my binding of a Label. I edited my question with my code :)

Comment: why have u created bindable properties ? this won't be needed as u r not using custom renderer .

also , Label already has , TextProperty; FontProperty;TextColorProperty, you can bind em easily . follow below link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36390545/can-you-make-a-clickevent-with-the-masterdetailpage-icon-text/36396688#36396688

Comment: Because if I don't do this, I can't bind different values passed in my xaml page

Comment: i don't use xaml,but same thing i have done with code in link , isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

[Effects](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/effects/introduction/) might be your choice.

> Effects allow the native controls on each platform to be customized, and are typically used for small styling changes. This article provides an introduction to effects, outlines the boundary between effects and custom renderers, and describes the PlatformEffect class.

If you want total control of listview, a renderer is still needed.