# Xamarin forms MasterDetail and PageRenderer

Tags: xamarin.forms, master-detail

Situation:
Building an application using Xamarin Forms and MasterDetail component.

Question:
How Can I render a specific page on Android based on a PageRender? and keep the Drawer?

Edit

```
public class MasterBacASable : MasterDetailPage
{
    public MasterBacASable ()
    {
        Icon = null;
        Title = "The title";
        Detail =  (new FirstPage ());
        Master = new AppMenuPage ();
    }
}
```

[assembly:ExportRenderer (typeof(BacASable.FirstPage), typeof(BacASable.Droid.FirstPageContentRennderer))]
namespace BacASable.Droid
{
    public class FirstPageContentRennderer : PageRenderer
    {
        public FirstPageContentRennderer ()
        {
        }

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged (e);
        var activity = this.Context as Activity;
        var v = activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.AndroidView,this,false);
        AddView (v);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Follow this for Xamarin.Forms [Master-Detail Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/master-detail-page/)

The base Concept is the following

```
public class MainPageCS : MasterDetailPage
{
    MasterPageCS masterPage;

    public MainPageCS ()
    {
        masterPage = new MasterPageCS ();
        Master = masterPage;
        Detail = new NavigationPage (new ContactsPageCS ());
        ...
    }    
}
```

Your `Master` is your drawer and `Detail` the Page (ContentPage, TabbedPage,NavigationPage,CustomPageRenderer ).

So each time you want to display a different page set the `Detail` property

```
Detail = new MyContentPage();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36390545/can-you-make-a-clickevent-with-the-masterdetailpage-icon-text/36396688#36396688

Comment: Hi and Thx. My problem is when trying to get the Spcecific androidView.

Answer (score 0):

I was just forgetting to override the OnLayout in the Renderer.
Thank you all.